# Facebook Offline AccessToken Issue in CronJob

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, cron

I have an issue of Facebook offline access-token please help me out how to solve this issue helps are definitely appreciated

That my code when i was tried

```
$access_token="AAACEdEose0cBAK2USdNINUVUuCNip2zlPyMoL19in3LzeZAP9ydifNV7oeBC2T4zdCZCUvhDW3FDxOcHzA6ofDHQX24Tbw1VwLGdzT0AZDZD";

$facebook_url="https://graph.facebook.com/".$dataPageId->PageID."/feed?access_token=".$access_token;
$facebookPageStatus=file_get_contents($facebook_url);
$fpsjson=json_decode($facebookPageStatus);
```

One more thing there is no Facebook session file in my code basically i want this functionality for cronjob... OR 
if i execute my code they generate an error like this

[image]

Comment: Maybe access token expire issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a lot of questions here about facebook api requests failing because of the use of file_get_contents. Check out these threads: [Unable to file_get_contents to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161127/unable-to-file-get-contents-to-work), [File_get_contents not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324524/file-get-contents-not-working), or just search for more threads: "[facebook] file_get_contents".

Other than that, I recommend you to stop using the offline_access since it is deprecated: [Deprecation of Offline Access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/)